# gRPC distribution of messages when using multiple completion queues

Tags: grpc

In gRPC C++ async API, if I create two completion queue on the server side, and I request on each of them the same method, how gRPC will distribute the work? Is it random, round-robin, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Each call is bound with the CompletionQueue you pass into it, and replies are pushed onto that same queue. Consider this test: modify the hello world example, create 2 queues, do 100 calls with cq1, 10 calls with cq2, and see how many replies you get on each queue.

See https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/async/ for details.

Comment: I edited my question to precise: on the server side. I think you was talking about the client side.